# Can I add menu items to the IOS Webkit Copy/Define pop up menu?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, webkit

I'm developing an app based in webkit for use on iPad. When a user selects some text, by default the Copy/Define (or just Copy if a phrase is selected) pops up. I would love to be able to append menu items to this menu or turn it off and retain the highlighting feature.

My end goal, is when a user selects some text I can have a 'create highlight' button go beside the highlighted text which then calls a JavaScript function that saves the highlight and surrounds the text in a span tag.

Having the Copy menu plus my own menu is plausible, but not exactly the best idea since it looks a bit clunky. I could turn off the Copy menu, but that will also disable the highlighting feature in webkit/iOS.

Any suggestions? I need to program this entirely in JavaScript(jQuery), CSS or HTML5.

Answer (score -1):

I am not much aware of Webkit / Webview interfaces for iOS, but had it be MacOS, yes it would have been possible with following approach,
1 -- You need to implement [WebUIDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001915)
2 -- Implement [ContextMenu Method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001915)

hope that helps...